# Creating app shortcuts on main screen will consume lot of memory?

Tags: ram, 9.0-pie

Latest android devices have enough RAM and Storage so when I was using 512 MB of RAM android phone customer care advised me to do not create shortcuts on main screen.

Now I'm using 3GB of RAM and 32 GB of ROM android device running on Android 9.0
So may I know is it same for latest devices.
Does it consume much space on RAM?

Comment: You have based your question on the assumption that the advice given by the customer care stands correct. That advise just doesn't make sense at all. A word of advise: whatever a customer care from any establishment says, take that with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What consume memory are the apps that sit in memory. Shortcuts are just links to apps, there are not the "main" programs themselves and are not running.  Many launchers are efficient and can handle a lot and lot shortcuts.

You have enough RAM and should not worry too much about how many shortcuts you have on your screen. Even if you only have 512MB, you should only worry if you had opened too many apps or apps such as games that might require a lot of memory thus reducing RAM and potentially slowing down the device.

A good point made on the comments is that launchers fetch shortcuts' icons, create a string for their names, etc, and that increase the memory used. However even then, it is argued that the memory usage won't have noticeable effects on the device.